# Is it possible to filter journald messages before they are filed?

Tags: logging, systemd, journaled

I have all kind of logs which are centralized with `journald`. A lot of them are not interesting and I could try to filter them at the source, but this not always possible. Moreover, some are interesting within a given level, while some are not.

Is there a way to filter, with `journald`, the events which are logged. I am especially interesting in **rejecting** known patterns, rather than accepting some.

Is there a good alternative to that approach, should it not be possible? (I was thinking about forwarding the events to logstash and dropping the less interesting ones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to filter, with journald, the events which are logged.
> I am especially interesting in rejecting known patterns, rather than
> accepting some.

`journald` (actually, `systemd-journald`) is the daemon responsible for event logging. By default, it does not do any filtering, it just accepts events and stores them.

If you want journald to filter out some messages, you can set `MaxLevelStore`, which filters by log level, or `LogFilterPatterns` to filter by a pattern applied to the message - that might be what you want. See [docs for journald.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) for details. You can also filter for individual systemd units, by setting `LogLevelMax` and `LogFilterPatterns` - see [systemd.exec docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html).

The other approach is to filter when displaying the logs, which is done with `journalctl`. journalctl lets you filter in various ways, e.g. by systemd unit:

```
journalctl -u nginx.service
```

Most of these filters do not allow negation, though, so they select messages, instead of excluding them. To exclude specific messages, you could use option `--grep`, which matches a regular expression, by crafting a regular expression which excludes what you do not want.

> Is there a good alternative to that approach, should it not be
> possible? (I was thinking about forwarding the events to logstash and
> dropping the less interesting ones)

That would be one option (though it might be overkill for just reading the logs). You could also go all the way and install a log viewer, such as [Graylog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graylog).

If you want a simple, quick solution, you could also dump the logs to a file with option `--output=...`, and then process that with your tool of choice. You can dump various text formats or JSON. JSON in particular will allow complex postprocessing, if you write a quick script in Perl, Python or whatever that parses the JSON and filters it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is that I receive quite a lot of logs, from various systems and I would like to get as much of low level logs from them (DEBUG), and filter before they hit the disk. The reason for that is that I have often cases where one interesting information is provided at DEBUG level (this is just an example) but it comes at the cost of 100 useless ones. This multiplied by several services fills up the logs unnecessarily. It would not be difficult to filter regex style, though. I am currently looking at fluend as the best compromise but I am open to other solutions.

Comment: Another possibility (which I used to some point but Logstash is a real pain to debug) was to forward to Logstash, filter there, and sent to elasticsearch (to view with kibana afterwards)

Comment: I'm also finding similar function to mute noisy warp-svc service. Finally reach here by google. After checking manual I think you can check LogLevelMax setting( man systemd.exec ). You can lower logging level if you don't need them, by unit.

Comment: @alfred: Thanks for pointing this out. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Note that LogFilterPatterns is not available for journald.conf. It is only available for "Unit configuration files for services, sockets, mount points, and swap devices" ie systemd.exec.